# iTextSharp word wrap

Tags: c#, itext, word-wrap

I am currently using iTextSharp to add dynamic text/image content to a PDF from a template.

I was wondering what construct is best to use when I need a word-wrap feature?

For example, I take in a description which can be up to 30 words long and it will span multiple lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple column text was the answer ;)  Can also be achieve using PDFPTable too.

Silly VS2008 just needed a restart for it to work -.-